# perl or sed: replace words with some relationship

Tags: sed, perl, variable

I use TeaCode, TeaCode has a [TeaCode language](https://www.apptorium.com/support/teacode/language), and in template text has these definition:

```
md5 converts text into MD5 hash value
uppercase makes all the letters UPPERCASE
capitalize Converts First Letter Of Each Word To Uppercase
camelcase converts text to camelCase
snakecase converts text to snake_case
dashcase converts text to dash-case
lowercase makes all the letters lowercase
sha1 converts text into SHA1 hash value
pascalcase converts text to PascalCase
remove_spaces removesallthespaces
lcfirst makes the first letter lowercase
ucfirst makes the last letter uppercase
```

for example:

```
For pattern vc ${name:word}, the template is:

class ${name.capitalize}ViewController: NSViewController {

    #
}
```

It means that if user types `vc main`, the output code will be:

```
class MainViewController: NSViewController {

    |
}
```

so I want the result is:

input: the words want to replace with template variable.

output: the template text has been replaced.

example1:

input text:

```
class MainViewController: NSViewController {

    // this is main text
    // this is maintain
    // this is Maintain
    // this is Main text
}
```

input:

```
main
```

output text:

```
class ${main.capitalize}Controller: NSViewController {

    // this is ${main} text
    // this is maintain
    // this is Maintain
    // this is ${main.capitalize} text
}
```

note: only replace main as a word, for example maintain, the main is not a word.

Comment: The question doesn't make a lot of sense to me. You are asking, among other things, a machine to read a string of text and to decide if it's a single word or if it's made up of multiple words. How is it going to do that? Example: input word is "toothpaste" and the instruction is to camelcase. So, is it "toothPaste" or is it just "toothpaste" since it's a single word? YOU know the answer (probably), but how can a machine decide in such cases?

Answer (score 0):

If I understando you correctly, you can try this with `sed`:

Example:

```
class FooViewController: NSViewController {

    // this is foo text
    // this is foobar
    // this is Foobar
    // this is Foo text
    // foo
    // Foo
    // BarFoo
    // barfoo
}


word="foo"
```

The command:

```
sed -e "s/^class .*Controller/class \${$word.capitalize}Controller/" -e "s/\( \|$\)$word\( \|$\)/\1\${$word}\2/" -e "s/\( \|^\)${word^}\( \|$\)/\1\${$word.capitalize}\2/" file
```

Output:

```
class ${foo.capitalize}Controller {

    // this is ${foo} text
    // this is foobar
    // this is Foobar
    // this is ${foo.capitalize} text
    // ${foo}
    // ${foo.capitalize}
    // BarFoo
    // barfoo
}
```